# Java inheritance hierarchy animal classes

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

I'm supposed to have a hierarchy of animals in my java project, but I'm confused on what should extend what.
Here are the instructions:

> Write classes or interfaces to represent the following:
>
> - Adoptable
> - Animal
> - Bat
> - Bird
> - BlueWhale
> - Dog
> - Emu
> - Fish
> - Goldfish
> - Mammal
> - Otter
> - Parakeet
> - Reptile
> - Turtle
> - WaterDweller
> - Whale
> - Winged
>
> You need to decide on the structure of the classes/interfaces. Consider:
>
> Which should be an abstract class? a concrete class? Which should be
>   an interface? How should the classes be related through inheritance?
>   In what classes should methods be placed? What methods should be
>   overridden? What information should be taken in as a parameter and
>   what information can be hard-coded into a class? Some additional
>   details/requirements:
>
> All animals have a method "isWarmBlooded" that returns a boolean. The
>   method can be in the class directly or inherited. All animals have a
>   name. All classes have a toString method that returns the animal's
>   name, whether the animal is warm blooded, and a list of all animal
>   names that apply to the animal. The toString method can be in the
>   class directly or inherited. Animals that can be adopted as pets have
>   a method "getHomeCareInstructions" that returns a description of how
>   to care for the animal. Animals that live in water (are water
>   dwellers) have a method "livesOnLand" that returns a boolean of
>   whether the animal also can live on land. Animals that have wings have
>   a method "flies" that returns a boolean of whether the animal can fly.
>   This part of the assignment isn't necessarily difficult from a
>   programming perspective. What you should spend time on is carefully
>   considering the design of you classes and how they should be related
>   through inheritance or interfaces

I'm not sure how to design this because I know a bird is winged, but so is a bat. Therefor bat would extend winged, but bats are also mammals. I can't have winged extend mammal because birds are not mammals. Also, whales and otters are watter dwellers, but are also waterdwellers. I can't have waterdwellers extend mammals (because whales/otters are mammals), but fish are not mammals and are waterdwellers. How would I make it so a bat is both winged and a mammal? The programming is the easy part, just struggling with the structure of the project. How can I structure this so it could work?

Comment: For example, make  Winged and Mammal interfaces and Bat a class implementing both interfaces. Keep in mind a class can only extend one class but implement many interfaces. Better still, Mammal can be an abstract class.

Comment: @user10527814 Shouldn't Mammal be an interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So in your modelling you have to think:

Which are *actual* animals?

e.g. whales, otters -> classes

which are a *type of animal*?

e.g. a bird. -> abstract class

Since every emu is a bird.
This is called the Liskov Substitution Principle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Which are *characteristics* of an animal?

e.g. WaterDweller, Winged -> those are interfaces.

Every class can have one superclass, it can have many characteristics, like being winged, or being a waterdweller, or adoptable

one addition for your bat example:

It *is* a mammal -> therefore it's superclass is mammal. It *is* winged - which is a characteristic - so it implements the winged interface.

```
class Bat extends Mammal implements Winged{
}
```

Comment: Let's say I have to classes. They are: Animal → Fish → Goldfish, and, Animal → Mammal → Whale. And let's say I want to use the interface Adoptable on them. The question is: Where should I implement the Adoptable interface? For example, should I implement it in the Animal class or in the Whale class?

Comment: if everything should be adoptable, go to animal, if just whales should be, go to whales. etc. You can also go for mammals, if only mammals should be adoptable