# How to write an Object Oriented Program to instantiate objects and interfaces with super class, sub-classes and interfaces

Tags: java, object, inheritance

In school, I was given this question:

Preamble: In OOP, a class is said to be instantiated when an object of the class is created. Analyse the Figure 1 below and use it to answer the following questions.

[image]

Using the concept of Inheritance and interfaces, produce a list of classes, objects and/or interface, indicating which:

i. is/are base, parent or super class(es). Answer to this is Animal Class
ii. is/are derived, child, sub class(es). Answer to this are the Bird, Reptile and Fish Classes
iii. is/are interface(s). Answer to this is the fly for don't fly or can sour high
iv. the keyword for implementing inheritance. Answer to this is "extends"
v. The keyword for implementing interfaces. Answer to this is implements.

b) Using your answers, above, create a Java OOP program that instantiates the required objects and call their related methods.

For this question, I was able to write the following code:

```
public class Animal {
public class Animal {

//  Properties gender, age, weight
  public String gender;
  public String age;
  public String weight;

//  Constructor to inherit for other classes
  Animal(String gender, String age, String weight) {
    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
    this.weight = weight;
  }

//  Methods to inherit
  public void sleep() {
    System.out.println("Animal can sleep");
  }

  public void move() {
    System.out.println("Animal can move");
  }

  public void eat() {
    System.out.println("Animal can eat");
  }

}


//Bird class inherits Animal
class Bird extends Animal {

  Bird(String gender, String age, String weight) {
    super(gender, age, weight);
  }
}

//Reptile Class inherits Animal
class Reptile extends Animal {

  Reptile(String gender, String age, String weight) {
    super(gender, age, weight);
  }

  public void leap() {
    System.out.println("Frog can leap");
  }

  Reptile Frog = new Reptile("Male", "1yr", "1kg");

}

//Fish Class inherits Animal
class Fish extends Animal {

  Fish(String gender, String age, String weight) {
    super(gender, age, weight);
  }

  Fish Shark = new Fish("Male", "3yrs", "150kg");
}


// Interface Fly
interface abilityToFly {
  public void Fly();

}


//Eagle inherits Bird and uses fly ability
class Eagle extends Bird implements  abilityToFly {

  Eagle(String gender, String age, String weight) {
    super("Female", "2yrs", "2kg");
  }



  @Override
  public void Fly() {
    System.out.println("It can Fly");
  }
}

//Chicken inherits Bird but does not have the ability to fly
class Chicken extends Bird implements abilityToFly {

  Chicken(String gender, String age, String weight) {
    super("Female", "1yr", "1kg");
  }

  @Override
  public void Fly() {
    System.out.println("It can not Fly");
  }
}
```

I am not sure if I have done this the right way and can anyone correct this code for me and tell me how to instantiate it. Thank you

Comment: Frogs are not reptiles. Now that I got that of my chest have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53117364/java-inheritance-hierarchy-animal-classes?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be little changed further to generalise things.

You have done `Encapsulation, inheritance` properly. You can handle the below things also little improved way.

`Reptile` and `Fish` should be a class which `extends Animal`. `Frog` should be another class which does `leap` and few other it's own properties. Similarly `Fish`

I am not sure about these classification. As per the `class` diagram, I am explaining `oops concepts` to you.

1. There can be `n` number of `reptiles` Each one can have it's own
   behaviour. Let's say `reptile1` sounds while eats whereas `reptile2`
   doesn't.

So you can have something as below.

```
public abstract Reptile extends Animal{
   public abstract leap();
}

public class Reptile1 extends Reptile {
   //Define leap behaviour
   //Define other behaviour and characteristics
}

public class Reptile2 extends Reptile {
   //Define leap behaviour 
   //Define other behaviour and characteristics
}
```

At the time of instantiating, you can do `Reptile frog = new Frog();`- `polymorphism`

2. You need to set class properties as `private` and add `getter,
   setters`. - `Abstraction`

> ```
>  private String gender;
>  private String age;
>  private String weight;
>
> public String getGender() {
>   return gender;
> }
>
> public void setGender(String gender) {
>    //validate if needed - only accepted genders 
>    //to avoid malformed data/input
>    this.gender = gender;
> }
> ```

3. I think that `Chicken` doesn't need to implement `fly` interface as it can not do that behaviour.

Apart from these, your `initialisation` looks good.